# Display objects within a function, how to NOT terminate the program after close the display?

Tags: python, python-visual

see the example:

```
from visual import *
def hello():
    newyear=2010
    sphere()
    return newyear
```

my problem here is when I call function hello(), a sphere display window shows up, and also prints 2010, however if I close the display window, the program terminates. That is not what I want, how can I avoid this?

also, in my code, I will also use newyear, say b=hello(), but I dont want it show the sphere when I want use newyear, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean 'terminates' instead of 'executes'?

Comment: @Felix: yes, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fork the process before hand.

(Totally untested)

```
import os
if os.fork() == 0: exit()
```

Placing that stanza at the start of your program should cause execution to continue in a forked process, detached from your tty. Someone can probably correct me though.